# Rank of the sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have two square matrices $M$ and $N$ such that $M^2=M$ , $N^2=N$ and $MN=NM=0$. I'd like to prove that $\operatorname{rank} (M+N)=\operatorname{rank} (M)+\operatorname{rank} (N)$. I know that $\operatorname{rank} (M+N)\leq \operatorname{rank} (M)+\operatorname{rank} (N)$. But how will i prove $\operatorname{rank} (M+N)\geq \operatorname{rank} (M)+\operatorname{rank} (N)$? Thanks for any help

Comment: Show that the images of $M$ and $N$ form a direct sum, and that this direct sum is in fact equal to the image of $M + N$.

Comment: Did you mean that I have to prove $x=My+Nz$ for every $x$?

Comment: You have two commuting projection matrices. Then the (linear sub)spaces at which they are projecting do only have the zero vector common.

Comment: No. (1) Prove that if $Mx = Ny$, then $Mx = Ny = 0$. (2) Prove that every vector of the form $Mx + Ny$ is in fact a vector of the form $(M + N)z$. The converse of (2) is also required, but it is obvious.

Comment: OK I got if $Mx=Ny$ then $Mx=Ny=0$.But how can I choose $z$ such that $Mx+Ny=(M+N)z$?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: can I conclude that $kernel (M) = N$ if $rank M +rank N = k?$, here $k \times k$ is the order of $M$

Comment: $MN=0$ says that each column of $N$ is in the kernel of $M$, so the column space of $N$ is contained in the kernel of $M$, they are not (necessarily) equal. Also, the coumn space of $M$ is contained in the kernel of $N$.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Thanks, but is $rank(M+N)=rank(M)+rank(N)$ correct when $M$ and $N$ satisfy the above relation?

Comment: Take $z = Mx + Ny$.

Comment: Thanks @user120974. Then, how can my last inequality be concluded?

Comment: What is the dimension of a direct sum of subspaces?

Comment: $dim (U+V)=dim(U)+dim(V)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $M^2=M$ and $N^2=N$ hence $M$ and $N$ are two projectors hence
$$\mathbb R^n=\ker M\oplus \operatorname{im} M=\ker N\oplus \operatorname{im}N$$
moreover $MN=0=NM$ so
$$\operatorname{im}N\subset \ker M  \quad\text{and}\quad \operatorname{im} M\subset \ker N $$
now let $y\in \operatorname{im} M$ so $y=Mx$ but $x=x_1+x_2$ where $x_1\in \ker N$ and $x_2\in \operatorname{im} N\subset\ker M$ so 
$$y=Mx=Mx_1=(M+N)x_1$$
hence 
$$\operatorname{im} M\subset \operatorname{im} (M+N)$$
we prove by similar method that
$$\operatorname{im} N\subset \operatorname{im} (M+N)$$
hence
$$\operatorname{im} M+\operatorname{im} N\subset \operatorname{im} (M+N)$$
finaly the other inclusion is simple so we have the equality and the result follows since we have
$$\operatorname{im} M\cap \operatorname{im} N=\{0\}$$